# manage inventory use-case narrative

Tags: system, use-case

i have this use-case "manage inventory" and this is my current main success scenario:

1. The secretary chooses manage learning module from his/her page.
2. The system redirects secretary to the manage learning module page.
3. Secretary chooses what function to do in the page.

Where can i add that the secretary can add or update the data inside the database?
can i put it inside the alternate sequence as:
A3a.) secretary add new record.
A3b.) secretary updates existing records.
?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The use case you name is too unspecific. It should be something that can be easily considered "done" after something has been executed.
2. The person would not directly interact with a database. That is implementation details.
3. What you probably are looking for is a **user goal**, that you should add to your use case description.